# Generate text with partial styling?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically create a paragraph with bold and italic parts but couldn't make it with text nodes. Tried appending text node to text area, \n works ok but no bold or italic and styling the area is another headache for me.

With the code below, tried with appending to 'p' element, but now \n doesn't work too.  What's an easy approach to create styled text such as "***Decision:***" as a part of generated string at the bottom of the code for a beginner?

Also trying to go for a clean and recyclable code but that might be a luxury for me.
Thanks in advance.

```
<script>

    function addBreak () {
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }

    function createlabel(label) {
        addBreak()
        var title = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("b"));
        title.innerHTML = "sdsd";
        addBreak()
    }

    function appendField(textField,text) {
        textField.appendChild(text);
        document.body.appendChild(textField);
        addBreak()
    }

    function createField(label,text) {
        createlabel(label)
        var textField = document.createElement("p");
        var text = document.createTextNode(text);
        appendField(textField,text)
    }

    function report (dataName1,dataName2,p,a) {
        var label = "1 - Names of the variables";
        label.bold();
        var text = dataName1 + \n + dataName2;
        createField(label,text);

        label = "2 - Formulate the hypotheses";
        var h0 = "There is no significant correlation between " + dataName1 + " and " + dataName2 + " (ρ = 0).";
        var h1 = "There is a significant correlation between " + dataName1 + " and " + dataName2 + "(ρ ≠ 0).";
        var decision
        var isP
        var isH
        if (p<a){
            decision = "Reject";
            isP = "p<a";
            isH = h0;
        }
        else{
            decision = "Fail to reject";
            isP = "p>a";
            isH = h1;
        }
        text = "H0:" + h0 + \n +
               "H1:"+ h1 + \n +
               "Decision: " + decision + " since " + isP + " ." +  isH;
        createField(label,text);
        
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you should use template strings for tihs stuff

Comment: `\n` is a line-break in plain text, it's not HTML. You can't combine HTML and plain text line-breaks. Also, [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#Technical_summary) can contain plain text only, there's no way to put markup in the value of `textarea`.

Comment: have you thought about using markdown for the text formatting and a plugin to convert markdown to html?

Comment: @germanio Honestly I'm a newbie on JS so I don't understand your suggestion. Isn't html already a markdown language?

Comment: @TolgaGülsuna ohh ok, take a look at this: https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax
You can write the text with this sintax, in a single html textarea, then use something like https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown#browser to process it and show it as html.

Comment: @germanio It looks neat. Is it possible to use this in combination with string variables?
What I'm trying to go for is this:
 https://jsfiddle.net/Tolga1084/vueogptL/2/

Comment: @TolgaGülsuna sure, you can create the markdown using template strings, like `let mymarkdown = \`my name is ${name}.\`; ` and then convert it to html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would recommend using template strings it allows you to write you code much more readable.

You can do it with this syntax

```
let text = `H0: ${h0} \n
            H1: ${h1} `
```

As you can see you can do new lines with it and you can put your variables in the string with this syntax ${}.
Then there is no need anymore to concat your string with the **+**

To style your elements you can do a span around your bold elements for example and then style it in your css file

```
let text = `H0: ${h0} \n 
            H1: ${h1} \n
            Decision: <span class="bol">decision<span>`
```

then in your css

```
.bol{
     font-weight: bold;
 }
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for the answer. 
Being a newbie, I tried it first with appending text node to p element; it printed it literally, no processing done. Then tried with p.innerHtml; it did work for span but had to swap '\n' for <br>. It got me what I wanted but what is your suggestion for the most appropriate way to print literal strings onto a page?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like to archieve?

Comment: Here is a working example of how I want the output to be. https://jsfiddle.net/Tolga1084/vueogptL/2/

This output so far is exactly like how I want it but since your example included '\n', i'm guessing you had some other method in mind for printing it, rather than using innerHtml on p element. 
There will be more paragraphs to dynamically output, so I'm looking for a more "reusable"? method.

Comment: you can also create a p element and then append an text node to the element like let p = `document.createElement("p")`, let tnode = document.createTextNode("bla") 
p.append(tnode) 
Maybe syntax is not correct but this is the idea

Comment: That's what I went for originally, using concatenated strings. Unfortunately it doesn't process anything; just prints plain text.
https://jsfiddle.net/Tolga1084/ovtw9ak5/5/

Comment: I have found this jquery syntax $(p')[0].html("<p>Hello, <b>World</b>!</p>"); but then you have to use jquery